# Mysql PDO automagic utf8 conversion after upgrade to PHP 7

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, utf-8, php-7

I just upgraded my server to Debian 9.1 and while I was at it, I also switched from PHP 5.6 to PHP 7. My application stopped working, and after some poking around, I found that when retrieving data from the database, the data appears to be automagically converted to UTF-8. In this particular case, I am storing some binary data in a varchar(255) column (charset latin1) and the conversion from Latin1 to UTF8 of course breaks the binary data. I assume that I should have made the column varbinary instead, but here we are, and it used to work correctly in PHP5.6. I wonder why this changed, why I cannot find any information about this incompatible change anywhere, and how to configure PDO to return the data unchanged.

Best,

Arno

Comment: Does it give you an error about why it is failing? Is it when trying to access it in a particular way or just when running a `select`?

Answer (score 1):

I found the fix myself: explicitly setting the character set to "latin1" when connecting to the database (I had omitted it before). Still wondering why this was changed and why I missed it in the release notes.

Comment: Not sure - but I assume that PDO is using `default_charset` if you don't set it explicitly in the `dsn`. The default for `default_charset` has already been `"UTF-8"` in 5.6 - That's why you won't find anything in the release notes. So check the differences in your `php.ini` files, if you want to know why.